# If condition in terraform to create user from yaml vars

Tags: terraform, artifactory

Variables are loading from yaml file

project_tst.yml

````
project_key: tst

user_config_data:
    - rt_env: adm
      groups: false
      disable_ui_access: true
    - rt_env: dev
      groups: true
      disable_ui_access: false
    - rt_env: prod
      groups: true
      disable_ui_access: false
    - rt_env: dev
      groups: true
      ro: true
      disable_ui_access: false
    - rt_env: prod
      groups: true
      ro: true
      disable_ui_access: false
    ```

`lookups.tf

locals {
  tst_project_file  = file("project_tst.yml")
  tst_project = yamldecode(local.tst_project_file)
}`
````

Any help to create 5 users from the yaml file using terraform

```
resource "artifactory_user" "users" {
    for_each  = local.tst_project["user_config_data"]
    admin                      = false
    disable_ui_access          = "${each.value["disable_ui_access"]}"
    email                      = 
    groups                     = [
        "readers",
    ]
    internal_password_disabled = false
    name                       = "${local.tst_project["project_key"]}_${each.value["rt_env"]}_user"
    profile_updatable          = true
}
```

If "ro" is "true" then the username should be

1. tst_ro_dev_user
2. tst_ro_dev_prod

Otherwise

3. tst_adm_user
4. tst_dev_user
5. tst_prod_user

Is this possible ?

As a work around I am now using two resources, one is for "ro" and other for without "ro". This works fine and yaml vars changed like below

```
user_config_data:
  rw:
    adm:
      groups: false
      disable_ui_access: true
    dev:
      groups: true
      disable_ui_access: false
    prod:
      groups: true
      disable_ui_access: false
  ro:
    dev:
      groups: true
      disable_ui_access: false
    prod:
      groups: true
      disable_ui_access: false
```

Comment: Where should those values be referenced, in `disable_ui_access` or `name`?

Comment: should be in name